# Java TimeZone conversions

Tags: java, timezone, utc, date-format, simpledateformat

I understand that java Date is timezoneless and trying to set different timezone on Java Calendar wouldn't convert date to an appropriate Time Zone. So I have tried following code

```
 public static String DATE_FORMAT="dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss";
 public static String CURRENT_DATE_STRING ="31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT";
 DateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
 dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
 System.out.println(dateFormat.parseObject(CURRENT_DATE_STRING));
```

but it outputs wrong date `Mon Oct 31 16:19:56` when it must be `12:19:56`?

Comment: you are not showing the whole code. Where is the time outputted?

Comment: System.out.println(dateFormat.parseObject(CURRENT_DATE_STRING));

Comment: I don't believe it messes up the minutes with.. 8

Comment: Your `DATE_FORMAT` string doesn't contain a `z` timezone code to parse the timezone in your date string. Also you need to use `HH` for the hours, not `hh` (`HH` is for the 24-hour clock).

Comment: EEST – Eastern European Summer Time

Comment: Even with 'z' in DATE_FORMAT and 'HH' it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is your date format string is using hh (12-hour clock) instead of HH (24-hour)

Secondly, your date format should specify that your date string contains the timezone.
(Alternatively you could uncomment the commented line, to tell it the correct timezone).

Thirdly, you should use a DateFormat to output the time to screen aswell...

Finally, UTC = GMT, so the UTC time is also 14:19:56

(GMT, 'British Winter Time', is the same as UTC, whereas BST is one hour ahead)

```
public class DateFormatTest {
    public static String DATE_FORMAT="dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
     public static String CURRENT_DATE_STRING ="31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
         DateFormat dateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
         //dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
         Date d= dateFormat.parse(CURRENT_DATE_STRING);
         dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
         System.out.println(dateFormat.format(d));
    }
}
```

Output: `31 Oct 2011 14:19:56 UTC`

HTH

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

On that date, at that time, in some eastern Europe time zones, the clocks were running two hours *ahead* of UTC. So the hour of 14 in UTC (GMT) will appear as 16 (not 12) in zones such as `Europe/Helsinki`.

```
        ZonedDateTime
            .parse
            (
                    "31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT" ,
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern
                    ( 
                        "dd MMMM uuuu HH:mm:ss z" , 
                        Locale.US 
                    )
            )
            .withZoneSameInstant
            (
                    ZoneId.of( "Europe/Helsinki" )
            )
            .toString()
```

> 2011-10-31T16:19:56+02:00[Europe/Helsinki]

## *java.time*

> I understand that java Date is timezoneless

Actually, a `java.util.Date` represents a moment as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Beware of `Date::toString`. That terrible `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating its text. This creates an illusion of that time zone having been part of the object. One of many reasons to never use this class.

> trying to set different timezone on Java Calendar wouldn't convert date to an appropriate Time Zone

You should be using the modern *java.time* classes, never `Calendar`. Specifically, use `ZonedDateTime` to represent a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

> "31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT";

Your input of `"31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT"` does not match your formatting pattern `"dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"`. That pattern fails to account for the offset of your input, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds indicated by the `GMT` at the end.

Firstly, do not exchange date-time values using such formats. Learn to use [*ISO 8601*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats for exchanging date-time values as text. The *java.time* classes conveniently use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating text, so no need to specify a pattern at all.

But if you must parse that particular input string of yours, define a formatting pattern to match.

```
String input = "31 October 2011 14:19:56 GMT";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MMMM uuuu HH:mm:ss z" , locale );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Notice how we specified a `Locale`, to determine the human language and cultural norms used in translation of your input.

> EEST – Eastern European Summer Time

Apparently you want to view this moment as seen in the time zone of eastern Europe. I will arbitrarily choose one of the several time zones in that area.

Be aware that `EEST` is not a real time zone. Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` or `EEST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId zoneHelsinki = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Helsinki" );
ZonedDateTime zdtHelsinki = zdt.withZoneSameInstant( zoneHelsinki );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zdt = " + zdt );
System.out.println( "zdtHelsinki = " + zdtHelsinki );
```

> zdt = 2011-10-31T14:19:56Z[GMT]
>
> zdtHelsinki = 2011-10-31T16:19:56+02:00[Europe/Helsinki]

Notice how the hour changed from `14` to `16` because at that moment the clocks in Finland were running two hours ahead of UTC.

> but it outputs wrong date Mon Oct 31 16:19:56 when it must be 12:19:56?

No the hour `14` is in UTC. Eastern Europe runs *ahead* of UTC, not behind it. As seen above, Finland on that day was running two hours ahead, so the little hand on the clocks of Finland were pointing at `4` (16 hour) rather than `12`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).  It's recommended by many StackOverflow users and is well documented with examples on timezone conversion.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What's the whole output? Date.toString() should print time zone. Maybe it's not in UTC in your case.